# Replace PHP script reading image alt and title values to reading image filenames

Tags: php, drupal

This script:

```
function theme_vscc_element_black_icons($vars) {
    $image_vars = array(
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme') . '/images/vscc/' . $vars['element'] . '.png',
        'alt' => t($vars['element']),
        'title' => t($vars['element']),
    );
    return theme('image', $image_vars);
}
```

It reads image's alt and title values that are called 'previous' and 'next', so to make it load the images, they need to be named as previous.png and next.png

What do I need to replace to make it read not the alt and title, but make it look for given file names like previous-black and next-black, so it would load the files named previous-black.png and next-black.png instead of looking for values in alt and title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding simple suffix for images like `'-featured.png'`